# confusion with For Loop Java

Tags: java, loops

Sorry i'm new to java, just need help with my school project.

I'm trying to implement a For loop for a deck of cards. I want my loop to keep adding cards till it has reached 5.

The count increases using the following URL: https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/draw/?count=1

count=1 needs to keep going up from 1 to 5. I think what i have below is correct but is this the right way to do it? and can i enhance it so there is an output at the end of it?

```
    int counter = 5;
    for(int i = 1; i <= counter; i++) { 
        String uriString = "https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/draw/?count="+i;
```

Comment: "_I think what i have below is correct but is this the right way to do it?_" Your loop looks fine by me, so yes, that's the right way to do it. "_and can i enhance it so there is an output at the end of it?_" As for enhancing it so there's output, I guess you mean retrieving the JSON-output of the URL? In which yes, _you_ can enhance it. (I'm being literal on purpose here. Since it's a school project, you'll have to figure some things out yourself first. If you get stuck trying to read the JSON on a particular problem we can help you, but we won't do your homework for you.)

Comment: Can i do a system.out.printin(i) ? so the 5 is printed. How can i read the JSON from the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal cards from 1 to 5, then yes it works correctly.

"can i enhance it so there is an output at the end of it?"

It depends on what do exactly you want. If you want to parse the result, then check this out: http://unirest.io/java.html